# How to get a list of country names based for each LocaleIdentifier?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nslocale

I need two NSArray one with all countries and the other one with the corresponding LocaleIdentifier.

Like:

```
  NSArray *countries = @[@"United States", @"Brazil", @"Spain"];
  NSArray *identifiers = @[@"en_US", @"pt_BR", @"sp_SP"];
```

So if anyone could lead me how can I get this programmatically or any other source I'd be thankful!

Comment: This doesn't quite make sense. The locale `en_US` represents both a language and a country. What about `es_US`? BTW - Spain is `ES`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a list of locale identifiers and their country name:

https://gist.github.com/jacobbubu/1836273

Answer (score 0):

You should try using NSLocale displayNameForKey:value: as explained on [this link](http://lists.apple.com/archives/Cocoa-dev/2007/Nov/msg00049.html)